# Pyspark (from csv file) is loading dataframe in a different format

Tags: dataframe, csv, pyspark

(I am new to pyspark)
I am trying to read a csv file into a pyspark dataframe as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("SampleWork").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('train.csv',sep=",",header=True,inferSchema=True)
```

But I am not getting expected result dataframe here. How to read this file correctly.
I have added the first 3 rows of the sample csv file here.

## csv file:

```
id,url_legal,license,excerpt,target,standard_error
c12129c31,,,"When the young people returned to the ballroom, it presented a decidedly changed appearance. Instead of an interior scene, it was a winter landscape.
The floor was covered with snow-white canvas, not laid on smoothly, but rumpled over bumps and hillocks, like a real snow field. The numerous palms and evergreens that had decorated the room, were powdered with flour and strewn with tufts of cotton, like snow. Also diamond dust had been lightly sprinkled on them, and glittering crystal icicles hung from the branches.
At each end of the room, on the wall, hung a beautiful bear-skin rug.
These rugs were for prizes, one for the girls and one for the boys. And this was the game.
The girls were gathered at one end of the room and the boys at the other, and one end was called the North Pole, and the other the South Pole. Each player was given a small flag which they were to plant on reaching the Pole.
This would have been an easy matter, but each traveller was obliged to wear snowshoes.",-0.340259125,0.464009046
85aa80a4c,,,"All through dinner time, Mrs. Fayre was somewhat silent, her eyes resting on Dolly with a wistful, uncertain expression. She wanted to give the child the pleasure she craved, but she had hard work to bring herself to the point of overcoming her own objections.
At last, however, when the meal was nearly over, she smiled at her little daughter, and said, ""All right, Dolly, you may go.""
""Oh, mother!"" Dolly cried, overwhelmed with sudden delight. ""Really?
Oh, I am so glad! Are you sure you're willing?""
""I've persuaded myself to be willing, against my will,"" returned Mrs. Fayre, whimsically. ""I confess I just hate to have you go, but I can't bear to deprive you of the pleasure trip. And, as you say, it would also keep Dotty at home, and so, altogether, I think I shall have to give in.""
""Oh, you angel mother! You blessed lady! How good you are!"" And Dolly flew around the table and gave her mother a hug that nearly suffocated her.",-0.315372342,0.480804970
b69ac6792,,,"As Roger had predicted, the snow departed as quickly as it came, and two days after their sleigh ride there was scarcely a vestige of white on the ground. Tennis was again possible and a great game was in progress on the court at Pine Laurel. Patty and Roger were playing against Elise and Sam Blaney, and the pairs were well matched.
But the long-contested victory finally went against Patty, and she laughingly accepted defeat.
""Only because Patty's not quite back on her game yet,"" Roger defended; ""this child has been on the sick list, you know, Sam, and she isn't up to her own mark.""
""Well, I like that!"" cried Patty; ""suppose you bear half the blame, Roger. You see, Mr. Blaney, he is so absorbed in his own Love Game, he can't play with his old-time skill.""
""All right, Patsy, let it go at that. And it's so, too. I suddenly remembered something Mona told me to tell you, and it affected my service.""",-0.580117966,0.476676226
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the custom `escape` character with the `multiLine` option.

```
df = spark.read.csv("test.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True, escape="\"", multiLine=True)

+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+
|id       |url_legal|license|excerpt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |target      |standard_error|
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+
|c12129c31|null     |null   |When the young people returned to the ballroom, it presented a decidedly changed appearance. Instead of an interior scene, it was a winter landscape.
The floor was covered with snow-white canvas, not laid on smoothly, but rumpled over bumps and hillocks, like a real snow field. The numerous palms and evergreens that had decorated the room, were powdered with flour and strewn with tufts of cotton, like snow. Also diamond dust had been lightly sprinkled on them, and glittering crystal icicles hung from the branches.
At each end of the room, on the wall, hung a beautiful bear-skin rug.
These rugs were for prizes, one for the girls and one for the boys. And this was the game.
The girls were gathered at one end of the room and the boys at the other, and one end was called the North Pole, and the other the South Pole. Each player was given a small flag which they were to plant on reaching the Pole.
This would have been an easy matter, but each traveller was obliged to wear snowshoes.|-0.340259125|0.464009046   |
|85aa80a4c|null     |null   |All through dinner time, Mrs. Fayre was somewhat silent, her eyes resting on Dolly with a wistful, uncertain expression. She wanted to give the child the pleasure she craved, but she had hard work to bring herself to the point of overcoming her own objections.
At last, however, when the meal was nearly over, she smiled at her little daughter, and said, "All right, Dolly, you may go."
"Oh, mother!" Dolly cried, overwhelmed with sudden delight. "Really?
Oh, I am so glad! Are you sure you're willing?"
"I've persuaded myself to be willing, against my will," returned Mrs. Fayre, whimsically. "I confess I just hate to have you go, but I can't bear to deprive you of the pleasure trip. And, as you say, it would also keep Dotty at home, and so, altogether, I think I shall have to give in."
"Oh, you angel mother! You blessed lady! How good you are!" And Dolly flew around the table and gave her mother a hug that nearly suffocated her.                                                       |-0.315372342|0.48080497    |
|b69ac6792|null     |null   |As Roger had predicted, the snow departed as quickly as it came, and two days after their sleigh ride there was scarcely a vestige of white on the ground. Tennis was again possible and a great game was in progress on the court at Pine Laurel. Patty and Roger were playing against Elise and Sam Blaney, and the pairs were well matched.
But the long-contested victory finally went against Patty, and she laughingly accepted defeat.
"Only because Patty's not quite back on her game yet," Roger defended; "this child has been on the sick list, you know, Sam, and she isn't up to her own mark."
"Well, I like that!" cried Patty; "suppose you bear half the blame, Roger. You see, Mr. Blaney, he is so absorbed in his own Love Game, he can't play with his old-time skill."
"All right, Patsy, let it go at that. And it's so, too. I suddenly remembered something Mona told me to tell you, and it affected my service."                                                                                    |-0.580117966|0.476676226   |
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+
```